# Difference between UdpClient.Send method and UdpClient.Client.Send method

Tags: c#, networking, udp, hole-punching

I can either send data throughout the udp protocol with the UdpClient.Send(byte array) or the UdpClient.Client.Send(stream) method. both methods work. the only differences are that on one method I pass a byte array and on the other I pass a stream.

quick example:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(localEndPoint);
// I can eather send data as:
udpClient.Send(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2 }, 3);
udpClient.Client.Send(new byte[5]);
```

Also which method will ensure that my data reaches it's destination without loosing information? I have read that the udp protocol does not ensure that all bytes reach it's destination thus is better for streaming video, audio but not for transferring files like I am doing. The reason why I am using udp instead of tcp is because it is very complicated to establish a tcp connection between two users that happen to be behind a router. I know it will be possible if one of the users enables port forwarding on his router. I managed to send data by doing what is called udp punch holing. udp punch holing enables you to establish a connection between two users that are behind a router with the help of a server. It will be long to explain how that work in here you can find lot's of information if you google it. Anyways I just wanted to let you know why I was using udp instead tcp. I don't now if it will be possible to send a file with this protocol making sure that no data is lost. maybe I have to create an algorithm. or maybe the UdpClient.Client.Send method ensures that data will be received and the UdpClient.Send method does not ensure that data will be received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP does not guarantee data delivery or order of them. It only guarantees if you receive packet successfully, the packet is complete. You need to make your network communication reliable with your own implementation. The two functions should not make any difference.

[UNIX Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) has a chapter for this topic. (22.5 Adding Reliability to a UDP Application). You can also take a look at [libginble](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) which supports NAT traversal function (with STUN  or relay) and reliability of communication.

This article, [Reliability and Flow Control](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/reliability-and-flow-control/), might also help you to understand one possible way to implement it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two methods, UdpClient is a wrapper around a Socket.  UdpClient.Client just gives you direct access to the Socket that UdpClient is using.  They both end up sending data through through the socket.

Neither one guarantees that all data will be received.  UDP makes no guaranty that 1. data will be delivered and 2. if it is delivered that it will be delivered in order.  If you need both of those (and can't use TCP) you'll have to write that code yourself.

The simplest protocol you can use is to add a sequence to each of your packets.  Have the server send one packet and wait for the response from the client that it received it an then send the next packet.  The sequence is important because the client may receive the same packet twice from the server, if the client's response to the server is lost.

Your sequence number can be the current position of the file's size in bytes - that's what TCP uses.

I'd recommend reading up on the TCP protocol so you understand the mechanisms it uses to handle reliability (remember both TCP and UDP are built on IP - TCP is just a more robust (and coplex) protocol so you can implement parts of it yourself)

Comment: I wish I could use tcp. I have not been able to establish a tcp connection between two users behind a nat. I have been able to do so with udp by doing udp punch holing with the help of a server. Maybe I can do punch holing with other protocol like ftp. I mean the reason why I want to do it with udp is because it is the only protocol that has enable me to connect two peers behind a nat without having to enable port forwarding on the routers